# astropy optimise get_body performance

Tags: python, performance, astropy

I'm using astropy and I have to call `get_body` a lot. I use NASA's `de430` ephemerides. The first call to `get_body` is always slow, because it's loading the ephemerides. The subsequent calls, however, are also slow. Not as slow as the first one, but still too slow for me because I have to call `get_body` a lot.

Is there a way to speed things up? I'm not sure why `get_body` is slow, maybe it's trying to load very precise data. In my case I need precision, but only 1 decimal (I don't need `120.3289749283749237`, `120.3` is enough). Is there a way to tell `get_body` to load but not as precisely, and will it make everything faster?

I tried to use less precise ephemerides `de432s` (10MB, while `de430` are 111MB), but it doesn't make anything faster at all.

Maybe there is a way to vectorise the calls to `get_body`, i.e. make it like this:

```py
get_body(["sun", "moon", ...], time, loc)
```

instead of:

```py
get_body("sun", time, loc)
get_body("moon", time, loc)
...
```

I would really appreciate if somebody could help. If you need some more info from me, please ask, I will try to provide as much as possible as quickly as possible.

**UPDATE**

Here is a code sample of how it happens in my app:

```py
from time import perf_counter

from astropy.coordinates import EarthLocation, solar_system_ephemeris, get_body
from astropy.time import Time

DATE = "2022-08-04 12:00"

solar_system_ephemeris.set('de430')
loc = EarthLocation(0, 0, 0)
time = Time(DATE)

# first call always takes long, so it's measured separately
start = perf_counter()
mars = get_body("mars", time, loc)
print(perf_counter() - start)

start = perf_counter()

jupiter = get_body("jupiter", time, loc)
saturn = get_body("saturn", time, loc)
pluto = get_body("pluto", time, loc)

mars = get_body("mars", time, loc)
jupiter = get_body("jupiter", time, loc)
saturn = get_body("saturn", time, loc)
pluto = get_body("pluto", time, loc)

mars = get_body("mars", time, loc)
jupiter = get_body("jupiter", time, loc)
saturn = get_body("saturn", time, loc)
pluto = get_body("pluto", time, loc)

mars = get_body("mars", time, loc)
jupiter = get_body("jupiter", time, loc)
saturn = get_body("saturn", time, loc)
pluto = get_body("pluto", time, loc)

moon = get_body("moon", time, loc)
venus = get_body("venus", time, loc)
sun = get_body("sun", time, loc)
mars = get_body("mars", time, loc)

sun = get_body("sun", time, loc)
moon = get_body("moon", time, loc)
venus = get_body("venus", time, loc)

sun = get_body("sun", time, loc)
moon = get_body("moon", time, loc)
venus = get_body("venus", time, loc)

sun = get_body("sun", time, loc)
moon = get_body("moon", time, loc)
jupiter = get_body("jupiter", time, loc)
saturn = get_body("saturn", time, loc)

sun = get_body("sun", time, loc)
moon = get_body("moon", time, loc)
jupiter = get_body("jupiter", time, loc)
saturn = get_body("saturn", time, loc)

print(perf_counter() - start)
```

The output is:

```
0.853644288000396
0.45204837000019324
```

As you can see, the time accrues. And I have to make the amount of calls that are shown above again and again.

**UPDATE 2**

For now, the solution I came up with is to minimize the calls to `get_body`. I was trying to do that across my code, but it was hard to do without making everything ugly. So I found a cleaner way, using `@cache`. If you haven't heard about it, it's a bit similar to `@lru_cache` but is a bit faster. You can use it like this, we have to wrap the `get_body` into another function to apply the decorator:

```py
@cache
def get_planet(body, time, location=None, ephemeris=None):
    return get_body(**locals())
```

You can also use `@lru_cache` if you need to limit the cache size. The `@cache` is available from python 3.9, you can't set the max size of the cache with it, but it's a bit faster than `@lru_cache`. More info on the docs: [@cache](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.cache), [@lru_cache](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache).

Now everywhere I was using `get_body`, I will use `get_planet`. This way I call `get_body` as less as possible, and it helps. I will try to investigate this problem further, however, and try to improve things even more.

Comment: It takes 25 ms on my machine for 1 call and 8 ms/call for 1000 calls. Most of the time is spent in a pure-Python unoptimized code (25% of the time from dicts alone)...

Comment: @JérômeRichard Hm, this is weird. Did you try it with NASA's ephemerides? Do you have this `solar_system_ephemeris.set('de430')` before your calls to `get_body`?

Comment: Sorry, I missed this part. That being said, I just tried (110 MB was indeed downloaded) and the speed of subsequent `get_body` calls are left unaffected in term of speed. How long does it takes on your machine to be considered as "slow"? (8 ms for this seems pretty slow to me actually)

Comment: @JérômeRichard I'm currently working on a simple code sample to demonstrate how my calls are being made, and how slow they are. I will update the question soon. Thank you for the collaboration so far.

Comment: @JérômeRichard I have added the code sample.

Comment: I got 3.287 and 0.475 for the first run. Then 0.014 and 0.384. I use AstroPy 5.1. I investigated the code and tried to write a function to compute N bodies and it is not much faster. I found a kind of precision parameter that can be tweak so to give a 1.5x speed up (x2 in extreme cases). The biggest problem comes from the library itself: it operates with very slow classes like Quantity which is at least 1000x time slower than what it should be and this is used a lot everywhere in the code... You can try to do the operation with multiprocessing but it will not be very convenient.

Comment: Using PyPy might help significantly if it is a supported module. Alternatively, you can open an issue on the GitHub project.

Comment: @JérômeRichard I'm also using AstroPy 5.1. What is this "precision parameter" you're talking about, can you please link to the docs? I was thinking about opening an issue on GitHub, and I will try it, in fact the first thing I did was searching if there is already an issue like this. I will also try PyPy. Thank you.

Comment: The parameter is unfortunately undocumented: it is a constant in the middle of the code. You can find this [here](https://github.com/astropy/astropy/blob/1998d8d2f269a556d198b870af07be409aa821d7/astropy/coordinates/solar_system.py#L420) (this function is called by `get_body`). I am not sure to understand the code correctly but it looks like a converging function to correct the distance (looping until a given precision is reached). The loop converge quickly though. Please consider putting the link to the issue in the question once posted as it may help future readers :) .

Comment: @JérômeRichard Too bad I can't tweak the parameter, maybe I could ask about it on GitHub issues. Also it's very nice of you to checkout the code for me, thank you :) I was planing to publish the link to the GitHub issue, I haven't created it yet though.